# Express configure doesn't work

Tags: express

I use

```
app.configure( function(){
    app.use(express.static(__dirname, '/'));
});
```

then I figured out it's the old version. Then I used this,

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
if ('development' == env) {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname, '/'));
}
```

but it still give me errors. My whole code is below.

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express();

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
if ('development' == env) {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname, '/'));
}

app.get('/people/:id', function(req, res){`

var customerId = parseInt(req.params.id);
var data = {};
for(var i = 0; i < people.length;  i++){

    if(people[i].id === customerId){
        data = people[i];
        break;
    }
}

res.json(data);
});

app.get('/people', function(req, res){

res.json(people);

});

app.lisen(8080);

console.log('Listening on express port 8080');

var people = [
        {id: 1, name: 'John', city: 'Lisbon', gender: 'male', total: '515.561', 
         orders: [
                    {id: 1, product: 'Shoes', total: '100'}
                 ]
        }, 
        {id: 2, name:'Abbie', city:'Orlando', gender:'female', total:'3445.34', 
         orders: [
                    {id: 2, product: 'Shoes', total: '200.561'}
                 ]
        }, 
        {id: 3, name:'Will', city:'Houston', gender:'female', total:'98754.00', 
         orders: [
                    {id: 1, product: 'Shoes', total: '300.561'}, 
                    {id: 3, product: 'Shoes', total: '330.561'}
                 ]
        }, 
        {id: 4, name:'Jim', city:'Paris', gender:'male', total:'15.26', 
         orders: [
                    {id: 4, product: 'Shoes', total: '400.561'}
                 ]
        }, 
        {id: 5, name:'Bryan', city:'Lisbon', gender:'male', total:'515.561', 
         orders: [
                    {id: 5, product: 'Shoes', total: '500.561'}
                 ]
        },  
        {id: 6, name:'Agulera', city:'Orlando', gender:'female', total:'3445.34', 
         orders: [
                    {id: 6, product: 'Shoes', total: '600.561'}
                 ]
        },  
        {id: 7, name:'Christeen', city:'Houston', gender:'female', total:'98754.00', 
         orders: [
                    {id: 7, product: 'Shoes', total: '700.561'}
                 ]
        },  
        {id: 8, name:'Matt', city:'Paris', gender:'male',total:'15.26', 
         orders: [
                    {id: 8, product: 'Shoes', total: '800.561'}
                 ]
        }
];
```

I'm quite new to express and I'm doing this by watching a video. so I want to configure it properly and run it. Please help me with this.

Comment: "gives me error", which error?

Answer (score 0):

spelling error

```
app.lisen(8080);
```

--->

```
app.listen(8080);
```

second...

global variables are bad strategy, put the var people as a local variable of app:

http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals

```
app.locals.people = "put the people data here";
```

Lastly, you should put responses and relevant http error codes to diagnose where there are errors:

for example.....

```
var yes = "yes";

if ( yes !== data.answer) {
console.log(err);
 res.status(401).send(err + "error, you do not have authorized access to this data"); }
else {
console.log("success! You are authorized!")
res.status(200).send(data);
};
```

Sends back json object data and "ok" status code if condition is met;

status codes:
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html